# CMake find wrong gcc version

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, version

My problem is simple : if I check the gcc version, I obtain `4.5.1`, but CMake find gcc `4.5.0` :

```
> /usr/bin/gcc --version
gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.5.1 20101208 [gcc-4_5-branch revision 167585]
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
> mkdir BUILD & cd BUILD
> cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- The Fortran compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran  -- works
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether /usr/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90
-- Checking whether /usr/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90 -- yes
```

**Who is wrong ?** CMake or Gcc ?

I use cmake 2.8.9, but I also have the bug with cmake 3.1.0.

I don't have the bug with gcc 4.7.2, 4.4.7 and 4.1.2.

Comment: Do you have a [`toolchain.cmake`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) setup in your CMake project?

Comment: No, I don't do cross-compiling. CMake detects the toolchain automatically.

Comment: Not necessarily cross-compiling, but it sounded you have concurrent GCC toolchains installed on your environment.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. I never used something called "toolchain" with cmake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering my own question.**

Actually, gcc 4.5.1 seems have a bug because the following simple code (correct according to the official doc : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) prints `4.5.0` when compiled with gcc 4.5.1 on my workstation.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::cout << __GNUC__ << "." << __GNUC_MINOR__ << "." << __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most likely Suse doing strange things to their version of gcc.

Answer (score 12):

The solution I found was similar to @usr1234567 that essentially CMake uses `cc` and `c++` wherever they are off the `$PATH`, which is not always the same as `gcc` or `g++`.

Specifying these compilers fixes the version shown by CMake:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ ..
```

Answer (score 1):

CMake uses `/usr/bin/c++` probably this is still pointing to gcc 4.5.0. If you want to set the compiler, add `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` to the compiler you like.

Comment: As I said, when I launch `/usr/bin/c++ --version` I obtain `4.5.1`. And CMake cleary indicates it's the path used...

Comment: You told us about /usr/bin/gcc, I was referring to /usr/bin/c++. Actually /usr/bin/cc would be better for the C compiler.

Comment: If I launch the following command `> cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/cc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/c++ ..`, CMake says `-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.5.0 
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.5.0`. If I launch `/usr/bin/cc --version`, it says `cc (SUSE Linux) 4.5.1 20101208 [gcc-4_5-branch revision 167585]`.

Comment: Check the value of `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__` Maybe this is not set right, at least that's the way CMake obtains it version (I guess).

Comment: Ok, it's in codes compiled with gcc. You're right, the variable is defined to 0 when I compile with gcc 4.5.1.

Comment: @Caduchon Thanks for the test. Would you mind to answer your own question and accept this answer? This way your question does not stay unanswered.